# PHP - Undefined index : id - the value is not retrieved

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Yes, I know there is a lot of 'Undefined index' questions floating around here and i have been looking through them before asking this question. I copied the codes from those questions to try and test it out but it still doesn't work for my own project. Also, I'm still a beginner in PHP.

So here is my problem. I wanted to try coding a simple edit form after I have finished coding the delete and view form.

This is my code

```
<?php
require("config.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo "id: ".$id;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contracts WHERE id= '$id'";
$result = $con->query($sql);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc()

?>

<form action="editform.php" method="GET">
ID:
<?php echo $id; ?><br>
Contract Title<br>
<input type="text" name="contract_title" value="<?php echo $row['contract_title']; ?>" /><br>

<input type="submit" name = "edit "value="Update" />
</form>

?php

if(isset($_POST['edit']) ){

$id = $_GET['id'];

$upd= "UPDATE `contracts` SET 
`contract_title`='".$_POST['contract_title']."',
WHERE `id`='".$_POST['id']."";

if($do_upd = $con->query($upd))
{
    echo "Update Success";
}
else
{
    echo "Update Fail";
}

}
?>
```

This is the before the error.

[image]

This is the error I received.

[image]

In line 3, the id is not retrieved after I clicked the button update.
It didn't retrieved the values.
What mistakes did I do in the coding and how do I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's a suggestion... test whether the `id` key exists in the `$_GET` array and that the value is not  NULL.   **`if ( isset($_GET['id']) ) { ... `**    http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Your URL in the second picture is clearly not passing the id. The reason for the undefined index error. That index is not defined... Also, just for best practice, note your submit button: <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Update" />.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right below:

```
<form action="editform.php" method="GET">
```

Add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
```

**Update:**

Fixed other errors in your code:

```
<?php
require("config.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];

echo "id: ".$id;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contracts WHERE id= '$id'";
$result = $con->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc()
?>

<form action="editform.php" method="GET">
    ID: <?php echo $id; ?><br>
    Contract Title<br>

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="contract_title" value="<?php echo $row['contract_title']; ?>" /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Update" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_GET['edit']) ){
     // needs escaping!~~~
    $upd= "UPDATE `contracts` SET `contract_title` = '".$_GET['contract_title']."' WHERE `id` = '".$id;

    if($do_upd = $con->query($upd)) {
        echo "Update Success";
    } else {
        echo "Update Fail";
    }
}
```

Please consider escaping your database input to prevent SQL injection

Comment: I copied the code. It displays no error yet it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Because afterwards you check `if(isset($_POST['edit']) ){` when it looks like you should check `if(isset($_GET['contract_title']) ){` since the form is GET 
`

Comment: Also `<input type="submit" name = "edit "value="Update" />` -> `<input type="submit" name = "edit" value="Update" />`

Comment: I added a corrected version of the code in my answer

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you. I'm beginning to understand now. I missed some of the coding mistakes. I copied your code. It works but it cannot update the data and it only displays "Update Fail". I wonder what is the mistake?

Comment: I am not sure, maybe you should escape `contract_title ` and print the query (`$upd`), that would help understand why it does not work. If I answered your initial question please flag my answer as accepted, I would appreciate it

Comment: Ok! Thanks for helping and giving me advise @Gab!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require("config.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo "id: ".$id;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contracts WHERE id= '$id'";
$result = $con->query($sql);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc()

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $contract_title = $row['contract_title'];

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}



if(isset($_POST['edit']) ){

$upd = "UPDATE contracts SET contract_title='$contract_title' WHERE id='$id'";

if($do_upd = $con->query($upd))
{
    echo "Update Success";
}
else
{
    echo "Update Fail";
}

}

?>

<form action="" method="POST">
ID:
<?php echo $id; ?><br>
Contract Title<br>
<input type="text" name="contract_title" value="<?php echo $row['contract_title']; ?>" /><br>

<input type="submit" name = "edit" value="Update" />
</form>
```